# How to do multiple routing (router-outlet) in angular2 RC4?

Tags: angular2-routing

**I am finding problem while multiple routing, its loading in single router-oulet how to tell the component to load in specific named outlet? I found out that there is a property in RouterConfig from which i can use outlet to name the router-outlet but i don't know to link it with HTML.**

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterConfig-type-alias.html

Define a UI with two router outlets..

```
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>                       
    <router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Then have a router config that routes a component into that space.

```
[{
   path: 'parent/:id',
   children: [
     { path: 'a', component: MainChild },
     { path: 'b', component: AuxChild, outlet: 'aux' }
   ]
}]
```

NOTE: the parent route's id parameter will be provided to both children.  Remove it if you aren't providing an id.

Comment: by using your solution i am Error: Cannot match any routes: 'parent.'

Comment: Use the live example from the Angular documentation.
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html

More information about the router is located here.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: but here also he haven't used any  child routing ( name any router-outlet).

Comment: i just want to know how to link the child routing from html using router-link ?